# Spring RestTemplate POST with parameters

Tags: spring, resttemplate

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    
    String endPointURL = "http://"+ display.getIpaddress()+"/api/brightness";
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(
            "{" + "\"brightness\":" + display.getBrightness() + "}",httpHeaders);
    restTemplate.put(endPointURL, request, String.class);
    
    String endPointURL1 = "http://"+ display.getIpaddress()+"/api/volume";
    HttpEntity<String> request1 = new HttpEntity<String>(
            "{" + "\"musicvolume\":" + display.getVolumelevel() + "}",httpHeaders);
    restTemplate.put(endPointURL1, request1, String.class);
```

I am trying this to post the data, but it show the error Unexpected end of file from server

Comment: Get the call working from Postman. Copy the working curl from Postman (the ‘</>’ on the right) and add that to the question.

Comment: Use any library jackson/gson to generate json data instead of manually creating with string.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing request method from put to post

instead

```
restTemplate.put(endPointURL, request, String.class);
```

use

```
restTemplate.post(endPointURL, request, String.class);
```

And check, you're using dynamic keys(brightness, musicvolume) while building the json request, those keys should not have escape characters, spaces, ancii ..etc

Comment: hi thanks for the replay but first time i am trying this it work fine but second time i am trying it give me error Unexpected end of file from server at line, restTemplate.put(endPointURL1, request1, String.class);